# how to convert my keras model en2.h5 into a tflite model encoder.tflite

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

when i want to convert my keras model en2.h5 into a tflite model encoder.tflite, i input below into my terminal

```
tflite_convert --output_file=/Users/yixun/Downloads/untitled/encoder.tflite \--keras_model_file=/Users/yixun/Downloads/untitled/en2.h5 --output_format=TFLITE
```

But the following error returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/yixun/anaconda3/bin/tflite_convert", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/yixun/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/lite/python/tflite_convert.py", line 515, in main
    app.run(main=run_main, argv=sys.argv[:1])
  File "/Users/yixun/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/platform/app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "/Users/yixun/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 300, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/Users/yixun/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/Users/yixun/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/lite/python/tflite_convert.py", line 502, in run_main
    _convert_tf2_model(tflite_flags)
  File "/Users/yixun/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/lite/python/tflite_convert.py", line 217, in _convert_tf2_model
    model = keras.models.load_model(flags.keras_model_file)
  File "/Users/yixun/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/save.py", line 146, in load_model
    return hdf5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
  File "/Users/yixun/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py", line 168, in load_model_from_hdf5
    custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/Users/yixun/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/model_config.py", line 55, in model_from_config
    return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/Users/yixun/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/layers/serialization.py", line 102, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "/Users/yixun/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 191, in deserialize_keras_object
    list(custom_objects.items())))
  File "/Users/yixun/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/network.py", line 906, in from_config
    config, custom_objects)
  File "/Users/yixun/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/network.py", line 1874, in reconstruct_from_config
    layer_output_tensors = layer._inbound_nodes[node_index].output_tensors
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not NoneType
```

what should i do?

Comment: The error tells you. You are taking an index with _inbound_nodes[node_index] but you are trying to do it with an invalid index. Because node_index = None, it's not going to work. You should fix your code so it either gets the right node_index, or it doesn't try to use None.

Comment: Please ask a real question like "to convert my keras model en2.h5 into a tflite model encoder.tflite"